# Custom validation error message for Validatable model

Tags: swift, validation, vapor

Is it possible to have custom validation error messages for the built-in `Validatable` protocol?
I have this validation:

```
static func validations() throws -> Validations<NewsletterListItem> {
    var validations = Validations(NewsletterListItem.self)
    validations.add(\.email, at: ["email"], .email)
    return validations
}
```

and it yields this message:

> ```
> {
>   "error": true,
>   "reason": "duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"uq:newsletter_list.email\""
> }
> ```

...which I'd like to improve.

Comment: You should create your Error Middleware yourself

Comment: Feel free to add a solution if you have on in mind. Always curious to learn more :) @HossamMaher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `Validatable` only adds the constraints, but doesn't validate them itself. So instead of providing the `Validatable` with an error message, you need to catch the error, check what error it is and then return/throw the desired response message. A good place to do so is the `.save()` call on a model:

The following example is inside a route handler of `POST /subscribe-to-newsletter`:

```
return try item.save(on: req).catchMap { error in
    if error.localizedDescription.contains("uq:newsletter_list.email") {
        throw Abort(.ok, reason: "You're already subscribed to newsletter")
    }
    throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```